# postgres locking with UPDATE FOR and foreign keys

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, concurrency, sqlalchemy

My Postgres tables:

performers

- id
- rank
- group_id REFERENCES groups

performances

- id
- pay
- performer_id REFERENCES performers

groups

- id

I often need to select all the performers from a group and update all their ranks. But this often leads to deadlocks since I'm doing an `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` select and other threads are `INSERT`ing at the same time.

Example of the error I see a lot (in Python SqlAlchemy):

```
DBAPIError: (TransactionRollbackError) deadlock detected
DETAIL:  Process 83182 waits for ShareLock on transaction 14282922; blocked by process 83171.
Process 83171 waits for ShareLock on transaction 14282925; blocked by process 83182.
HINT:  See server log for query details.
 'SELECT performers.id AS performers_id, performers.rank AS performers_rank, performers.group_id AS performers_group_id \nFROM performers \nWHERE performers.group_id = %(group_id_1)s FOR UPDATE' {'group_id_1': 2}
```

I've [found](http://bytes.com/topic/postgresql/answers/174929-deadlocks-sharelocks-transactions) a few [examples](http://rhaas.blogspot.com/2011/10/deadlocks.html) of this [behavior](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Deadlock-with-ShareLocks-td1938580.html) around as well.

How can I fix this? Can I switch to a different transaction locking level? I'd rather not just abort and have to retry - I want the database to take care of this contention for me.

There must be some way to fix this - what I want to do is quite simple.

Comment: When inserting into `performances`, commit after each different `performer_id` to avoid cross-locking with the UPDATEs. The fact that it's a `ShareLock` strongly suggests that it's taken for the FK.

Comment: The error message that PostgreSQL sends back to the client is lacking in information about the other transaction, to avoid leaking information to the client.  What does the PostgreSQL log file have to say about both transactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the deadlocks, if all concurrent write operations go about it in the **same unique order**. Add `ORDER BY` to your locking statement, and use the same sort order everywhere. Something like:

```
SELECT ... FROM performers WHERE ... ORDER BY performers.id FOR UPDATE
```

Where `id` would be the primary key (or any other stable, unambiguous combination of columns).

Also, if your operations involve multiple columns, do the locking in strictly the same sequence across tables.

More details in [this thread in pgsql-general list](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/freemail.20070030161126.43285@fm10.freemail.hu#freemail.20070030161126.43285@fm10.freemail.hu).
[Or in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE).

Keep triggers (and foreign key constraints) to the necessary minimum. Either way, first sort out the `FOR UPDATE` locks. That might just solve your problems. If not, consider a different [transaction isolation level](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/transaction-iso.html). [Serializable](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE) should do the trick. But then you *have to* be prepared to retry transactions until they succeed.

Comment: what about inserts? this obviously wouldn't apply there, correct?

Comment: @lollercoaster: Correct. You can't lock what's not there (yet). I don't see how INSERTs would deadlock, though? You might get a duplicate key violation, but that's a different kind of problem.

Comment: yes, I get deadlock when I INSERT into the performance table many values at once from different threads - I suspect because of the foreign key? I'm actually not sure why.

Comment: here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021249/postgresql-deadlock, and here's another: http://www.qcode.co.uk/postgresql-sharelock-deadlocks/

Comment: @lollercoaster: Right, foreign keys might do a number on you.

Comment: Why is that? And ugh - so how should I fix that?

Comment: ok thanks. one last question: why would I have to retry transactions? can't they just wait until the locks are free

Comment: @lollercoaster: That's how serializable transaction isolation works. Some concurrent operations would lead to inconsistent states or be ambiguous after a concurrent change. To be sure (and also with regard to performance) such transactions are rolled back with a serialization failure, and you just retry.